# C# get Dictionary class value

Tags: c#

I have small problem with Dictionary.

Here is little bit code:

```
string user = UserList
  .Where(p => p.Key == im.SenderConnection.RemoteUniqueIdentifier)
  .Select(p => p.Value.Username)
  .ToString();
Console.WriteLine(user);

public class User
{
        public string Username;
}
```

And that writes to console:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[System.Int64,ChatServer.User],System.String]

Comment: All the answers seem to assume you want to retrieve a single name and print it to console. Is that the case, or were you expecting that printing to console would automatically iterate the query for multiple users ?

Comment: If `UserList` is `Dictionary` why not simply `UserList[im.SenderConnection.RemoteUniqueIdentifier].UserName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're calling `ToString` on the result of a `Select`.

`Select` is a projection.. and as such, it still returns a collection. You should call `FirstOrDefault` and retrieve the name:

```
string user = UserList
    .Where(p => p.Key == im.SenderConnection.RemoteUniqueIdentifier)
    .Select(p => p.Value.Username)
    .First();

Console.WriteLine(user);
```

Or shorter:

```
string user = UserList
    .First(p => p.Key == im.SenderConnection.RemoteUniqueIdentifier)
    .Value.Username;
```

Comment: As a note, the second one would return the entire row from the source vs the first one which would only bring back a single column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string user = UserList.Where(p => p.Key == im.SenderConnection.RemoteUniqueIdentifier).Select(p => p.Value.Username).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

You are Selecting filtered UserList, and not a particular user. Add your Filter to `FirstOrDefault` to get specific user.